# Data (sum of rs)for multiple months for each month diffrent

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server-2008

I am really new to sql

This is my query:

```
select rmname, sum(cast (PROPOSEDLIMIT as int)) as january
from los_ext 
where applicationdate between '01-01-2016' and '01-31-2016'
group by RMNAME
```

I want this for every month in single query without using date `between function` always.

How can i do this?

I want my output as:

```
RMNAME   JAN   FEB   MARCH  APRIL   ....
Nitin    2222  3333  33333  34422   333
```

where sum of propsed limit is to be taken out.

Comment: which `RDBMS` are you using actually? `MySQL` or `SQL Server`?

Comment: add some sample data plz

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following query:

```
select 
    rmname, 
    sum(CASE WHEN MONTH(applicationDate) = 1 THEN cast (PROPOSEDLIMIT as int) ELSE 0 END) as january,
    sum(CASE WHEN MONTH(applicationDate) = 2 THEN cast (PROPOSEDLIMIT as int) ELSE 0 END) as February,
    sum(CASE WHEN MONTH(applicationDate) = 3 THEN cast (PROPOSEDLIMIT as int) ELSE 0 END) as March,
    sum(CASE WHEN MONTH(applicationDate) = 4 THEN cast (PROPOSEDLIMIT as int) ELSE 0 END) as April,
    sum(CASE WHEN MONTH(applicationDate) = 5 THEN cast (PROPOSEDLIMIT as int) ELSE 0 END) as May,
    sum(CASE WHEN MONTH(applicationDate) = 6 THEN cast (PROPOSEDLIMIT as int) ELSE 0 END) as June,
    sum(CASE WHEN MONTH(applicationDate) = 7 THEN cast (PROPOSEDLIMIT as int) ELSE 0 END) as July,
    sum(CASE WHEN MONTH(applicationDate) = 8 THEN cast (PROPOSEDLIMIT as int) ELSE 0 END) as August,
    sum(CASE WHEN MONTH(applicationDate) = 9 THEN cast (PROPOSEDLIMIT as int) ELSE 0 END) as September,
    sum(CASE WHEN MONTH(applicationDate) = 10 THEN cast (PROPOSEDLIMIT as int) ELSE 0 END) as October,
    sum(CASE WHEN MONTH(applicationDate) = 11 THEN cast (PROPOSEDLIMIT as int) ELSE 0 END) as November,
    sum(CASE WHEN MONTH(applicationDate) = 12 THEN cast (PROPOSEDLIMIT as int) ELSE 0 END) as December
    from los_ext 
    group by RMNAME,MONTH(applicationDate)
```

You may gather some knowledge on [Pivot Table](http://www.artfulsoftware.com/infotree/qrytip.php?id=78).

**Note:** The above query will sum up the data of same months although the months may belong to different years.

`For example 2015 February and 2014 February will be summed up to the same slot.`

In order to avoid this you may add a `date range in where clause like you did`.

So adding that date range in the where clause the query would look like below:

```
select 
    rmname, 
    sum(CASE WHEN MONTH(applicationDate) = 1 THEN cast (PROPOSEDLIMIT as int) ELSE 0 END) as january,
    sum(CASE WHEN MONTH(applicationDate) = 2 THEN cast (PROPOSEDLIMIT as int) ELSE 0 END) as February,
    sum(CASE WHEN MONTH(applicationDate) = 3 THEN cast (PROPOSEDLIMIT as int) ELSE 0 END) as March,
    sum(CASE WHEN MONTH(applicationDate) = 4 THEN cast (PROPOSEDLIMIT as int) ELSE 0 END) as April,
    sum(CASE WHEN MONTH(applicationDate) = 5 THEN cast (PROPOSEDLIMIT as int) ELSE 0 END) as May,
    sum(CASE WHEN MONTH(applicationDate) = 6 THEN cast (PROPOSEDLIMIT as int) ELSE 0 END) as June,
    sum(CASE WHEN MONTH(applicationDate) = 7 THEN cast (PROPOSEDLIMIT as int) ELSE 0 END) as July,
    sum(CASE WHEN MONTH(applicationDate) = 8 THEN cast (PROPOSEDLIMIT as int) ELSE 0 END) as August,
    sum(CASE WHEN MONTH(applicationDate) = 9 THEN cast (PROPOSEDLIMIT as int) ELSE 0 END) as September,
    sum(CASE WHEN MONTH(applicationDate) = 10 THEN cast (PROPOSEDLIMIT as int) ELSE 0 END) as October,
    sum(CASE WHEN MONTH(applicationDate) = 11 THEN cast (PROPOSEDLIMIT as int) ELSE 0 END) as November,
    sum(CASE WHEN MONTH(applicationDate) = 12 THEN cast (PROPOSEDLIMIT as int) ELSE 0 END) as December
    from los_ext 
    WHERE applicationdate between '01-01-2016' and '31-12-2016'
    group by RMNAME,MONTH(applicationDate)
```

Answer (score 0):

Do the `cast` and `month` stuff in a derived table (to save some typing, and become ANSI SQL compliant.):

```
select rmname,
       sum(case when mnth = 1 then proplim else 0 end) as jan,
       sum(case when mnth = 2 then proplim else 0 end) as feb,
       ...
       sum(case when mnth = 12 then proplim else 0 end) as dec
from
(
  select rmname, cast (PROPOSEDLIMIT as int) proplim, MONTH(applicationDate) mnth
  from los_ext 
  where applicationdate between '01-01-2016' and '01-31-2016'
) dt
group by RMNAME
```